# Code to calculate minimumZoomScale behaves differently on iOS 8 and iOS 9

Tags: ios, image, view, scroll, zooming

Some months ago I wrote a code to fit `UIImageView` in `UIScrollView` by the smallest side, with the ability to zoom that `UIImageView` in and out. This code works perfectly in iOS 8, but in iOS 9 it places `UIImageView` inside the `UIScrollView` with the wrong size. Here are the examples of what it looks like on the different OSes (don't mind the localization differences):

iOS 8

[image: iOS 8 result]

iOS 9

[image: iOS 9 result]

The code is used to calculate the zoom level (in Swift):

```
let imageRatio = image.size.height / image.size.width
let scrollRatio = scrollView.frame.size.height / scrollView.frame.size.width

if imageRatio > scrollRatio {
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scrollView.frame.size.width / image.size.width
}else{
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scrollView.frame.size.height / image.size.height
}

if scrollView.minimumZoomScale > 1 {
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scrollView.minimumZoomScale
}else{
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1
}

scrollView.zoomScale = scrollView.minimumZoomScale

let x = (scrollView.contentSize.width / 2) - (scrollView.bounds.size.width / 2)
let y = ((scrollView.contentSize.height / 2) - (scrollView.bounds.size.height / 2)) * scrollView.minimumZoomScale

scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x, y)
```

I use auto layout feature. So, the question is how can I achieve iOS 8 behavior on iOS 9?

Comment: Could you show how the constraints are being set?

Comment: Have you checked the size and position of the scroll view? Verify that and the layout of the views for the constraints first.